# How to resolve these memory leak in Doubly Linked List?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor, doubly-linked-list

I've been trying to remove the memory leak with simple delete [] name but I don't think it was successfully deleted because I still had memory leak. I also have a DeleteAll() function that traverse with the nodes but that don't seem to delete the object name.

The code below is under the add function and I think this might be the cause of my memory leak:
Under CDoublyLinkedList class

```
        CListNode*      work        = NULL;                 // holds head
        CListNode*      prev        = NULL;                 // previous
        CListNode*      newData     = new CListNode();      // instantiation of node class
        char* name = NULL;                                  //char array for name

        /// ________Increase array size of name depending on input
        name = new char[strlen(iName) + 1];
        /// ________Copy string to char
        strcpy_s(name, strlen(iName) + 1, iName);

        newData->SetName(name);     // Set user input to character list
```

My destructor only contains the delete all function under the same class

```
void DeleteALL()
    {
        CListNode* next;
        CListNode* current;

        current = head;
        while(current != NULL) {
            next = current->GetNext();
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
        current = NULL;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
```

this is my main:

```
CDoublyLinkedList       element         =       new CDoublyLinkedList;      //list object
Switch(option) {
            /// ____Option Add name
            case '1':
                cout << "Enter name:" << "\t";
                cin >> temp;

                /// ________If input is not 4-25 characters<br></br>
                /// ____________Loop while input is not 4-25 characters<br></br>
                /// ________________Ask for new input<br></br>
                /// ____________End loop<br></br>
                /// ________End if<br></br>
                if((temp.length() >= 3) == false
                    || (temp.length() <= 25) == false) {

                    while((temp.length() >= 3) == false
                        || (temp.length() <= 25) == false) {

                        cout << "Input should be 3-25 characters. Try again." << "\n";
                        cout << "Enter name:" << "\t";
                        cin >> temp;
                    }
                }
                /// ________Add input to list
                element->AddSortList(temp.c_str());
```

I deleted the object on my main method by:

```
if(element != NULL) {
        delete[] element;
        element = NULL;
    }
```

Class CNode only contains get and set

```
class CListNode
{
private:
    CListNode*          mNext;              // Next item pointer
    CListNode*          mPrev;              // Previous item pointer
    char*               mNameElement;       // List element pointer

public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Node initializer to set as NULL
    /// </summary>
    /// <dt>Date:</dt>
    /// 2019/10/03 Created  by JAC.Tayag (SAT-A)    TRAINING
    CListNode()
    {
        mNext = NULL;
        mPrev = NULL;
    }

    ~CListNode()
    {
        CListNode* next;
        CListNode* current;

        current = mPrev;
        while(current != NULL) {
            next = current->GetNext();
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
        current = NULL;
        mNext = NULL;
        mPrev = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Assign input name
    /// </summary>
    /// <dt>Date:</dt>
    /// 2019/10/03 Created  by JAC.Tayag (SAT-A)    TRAINING
    void SetName(char* iNameElement)
    {
        mNameElement = iNameElement;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assign next pointer
    /// </summary>
    /// <dt>Date:</dt>
    /// 2019/10/03 Created  by JAC.Tayag (SAT-A)    TRAINING
    void SetNext(CListNode* iNext)
    {
        mNext = iNext;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assign previous pointer
    /// </summary>
    /// <dt>Date:</dt>
    /// 2019/10/03 Created  by JAC.Tayag (SAT-A)    TRAINING
    void SetPrev(CListNode* iPrev)
    {
        mPrev = iPrev;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return input name
    /// </summary>
    /// <dt>Date:</dt>
    /// 2019/10/03 Created  by JAC.Tayag (SAT-A)    TRAINING
    char* GetName()
    {
        return mNameElement;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return next pointer
    /// </summary>
    /// <dt>Date:</dt>
    /// 2019/10/03 Created  by JAC.Tayag (SAT-A)    TRAINING
    CListNode* GetNext()
    {
        return mNext;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return previous pointer
    /// </summary>
    /// <dt>Date:</dt>
    /// 2019/10/03 Created  by JAC.Tayag (SAT-A)    TRAINING
    CListNode* GetPrev()
    {
        return mPrev;
    }
```

Comment: What is a `CDoublyLinkedList`? What is `CListNode` ? How do you know you have a memory leak?

Comment: @John3136 I've been using this:

if(_CrtMemDifference(&memCheckDiff, &memCheckStart, &memCheckEnd)) {
  _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&memCheckDiff);
  _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&memCheckStart);
  _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&memCheckEnd);
 }
 else {
  _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&memCheckDiff);
  _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&memCheckStart);
  _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&memCheckEnd);
 }

My problem was how to delete an object inside of a function

Comment: @John3136 I have added the CNode for your reference

Comment: At least one memory leak comes from failing to free `mNameElement` in the node destructor. And the node shouldn't be freeing the entire list anyway. it should only clean up *itself*. The list (the CDoubleLinkedList that wraps this whole thing) should be responsible for iteration and cleanup. Trying to do it inter-per-node is a recipe for disaster and chaos of edge cases. Further, I don't see a single thing besides `name` in this code that is array-allocated, so any use of `delete[] element` is automatically a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete same as single linked list.

```
node* element = head;
while( element != 0 ) {
    node* next = element->next;
    delete element;
    element = next;
}
head = 0;
```

Comment: I will place on my main?

Comment: you can place in any function you are goint to deleting. rate up and accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: but if I placed it on my function, it would also delete it on the list?